# how to setup a proxy smtp server?

Tags: email, email-server

We have a product where we need to get in the middle of all emails the company is sending

Is there a way to
1. configure outlook exchange to relay all email through an smtp proxy(hopefully with ssl connection) and how?
2. Is there a way to do this with business gmail app? and how?

Do all systems out there support such a proxy?  (From looking at gmail, I am thinking no?).  This may limit my customer set "or" customers would have to switch email providers :( ouch, painful.  Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want an smtp proxy, you just want to configure your internal mail relay to do what you need to do.  So, configure your Exchange server to send all mail via a single mail relay (sometimes called a smarthost).  For any other mail 'servers' they would also need to use your mail relay.  This may or may not be possible depending on the third party cloud service in question.

Comment: Agreed. It's fairly trivial to set up a small linux server as a relay/journaling server using postfix. It's possible that another exchange box could be configured as a relay, but that may add more complexity than is necessary.

Comment: actually, I think gmail business apps has a setting (at least heard from a friend and have not verified yet)...they did this so as business convert they can keep existing systems in place so outgoing mail still goes through those systems (or else they would never get them as a customer) or at least that is how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If Outlook users use MAPI or RPC over HTTPS it will not allow you to deliver mails through  the SMTP Proxy. On the other and you can set up an SMTP connector in Exchange to send all external mails to the SMTP proxy for relay.